# How can I add transparent watermark to PDF printout using reportlab python library

Tags: python, reportlab, pypdf

I have to draw a watermark in my dynamically generated PDF Print.

I did it using the pyPdf library(By merging the Original PDF and the PDF with watermark). 
 http://wa5pb.freeshell.org/motd/?p=769

My problem is, I have to make the watermark image transparent, without using the mask parameter of drawImage feature in reportlab library, Since it is manual. Any suggestions?

Thanks!.

Comment: You could just make the actual watermark image transparent, and reportlab should draw it correctly. Since you're drawing it manually onto the canvas, just make sure you draw it after any objects in the background, and before any objects it should appear behind.

Comment: yup, agree with @Nitzle. Achievable with photoshop.